# How to create a new Google Sheet using API v4 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets-api

I've been researching Google Sheets API and the Google Guide, but I can't seem to find any examples to create a new Google Sheet (workbook). I can read from a sheet, but figure out how to create a new one.

Below is the code I found to read from Google Sheets:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define request parameters.
        string spreadsheetId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

        ValueRange response = request.Execute();
        IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
        if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
            foreach (var row in values)
            {
                // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 - 4
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[4]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
```

Comment: The code you've included does not attempt to do what you want - what we need to see is a [mcve] with a specific programming problem you're trying to solve. As it stands, it appears that you're specifying a new behavior that the given code should have, and questions of that sort are off-topic here. If you can re-frame your question with YOUR attempt to implement that behavior and a SPECIFIC problem you ran into, it would get more specific answers.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed, as the question is legitimate, but poorly worded.  The answer is:
// nuget Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
Spreadsheet sheet = new Spreadsheet();
sheet.Properties = new SpreadsheetProperties();
sheet.Properties.Title = "some title";
var s1 = service.Spreadsheets.Create(sheet);
var s2 = s1.Execute();
Console.WriteLine($"The ID of the new spreadsheet is {s2.SpreadsheetId}");

Answer (score 1):

For Sheetsv4, I suggest using [Method.spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) as it's *creates a spreadsheet, returning the newly created spreadsheet*. You can check all the supported methods of the Sheets APIv4 in the [Sheetsv4 reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/).